# Repository doesn't exist when in fact it exists while trying to deploy a model on Sagemaker using Mlflow and Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker, aws-code-deploy, mlflow

I try to deploy my first ML model using this video as a reference (correct timecode): https://youtu.be/FsoSBsrcx9Q?t=2801

everything is right until the deploy.py, i changed the code from the video and after in the command line i just executed the .py and this error pops out:

"The repository with name 'mlflow-pyfunc' does not exist in the registry with id ''"

Or, if i take a look in ECR, it does exist:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7cbq.png)

I don't know what to do

The version in the video is mlflow 1.18.0, currently its mlflow 2.2.2 so i believe the docs changed. Here is the code i used to deploy the model:

```
import mlflow.sagemaker as mfs
from mlflow.deployments import get_deploy_client


experiment_id = ''
run_id = ''
region = ''
aws_id = ''
arn = ''
app_name = 'btcprediction'
model_uri = f'mlruns/{experiment_id}/{run_id}/artifacts/rnn-btc-forecast'
tag_id = '2.2.2'

image_url = aws_id + '.dkr.ecr.' + region + '.amazonaws.com/mlflow-pyfunc:' + tag_id

config = dict(execution_role_arn=arn, image_url=image_url)
client = get_deploy_client("sagemaker")
client.create_deployment(name=app_name, model_uri=model_uri)
```

it seems to work

Comment: Is your ECR repository tagged with 2.2.2 as well? Can you try copying the image URI directly from ECR (along with the tag) and executing your deploy function?

Comment: yes, it's tagged with 2.2.2 and i pasted the image URI from ECR and it still doesn't work, the issue may come from the last line as it's the only thing that differs from the tutorial (in the tutorial, mlflow 1.18 had a method that differs from mlflow 2.2.2)